# How can I encode a cURL response to be a JSON object?

Tags: php, ajax, post, curl

I'm trying to `POST` to a PHP controller using jQuery Ajax. I then want my controller to retrieve data from an API and return the data to my AJAX function.

Here is my javascript:

```
$(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/mycontroller/myaction/',
        success: function(data) {       
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Here is my action in my controller:

```
public function myaction() {

    $ch = curl_init();

    $endPoint = 'https://endpointfortheapi.com';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endPoint); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $response = json_encode($response);

    echo $response;

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

This seems to work, however, when I use `json_encode()` the array is returned as an escaped string, not a json object. When I `console.log(data)` in my AJAX request, I see a string like this:

```
"[{\"firstProperty\":\"firstValue\",\"secondProperty\":\"secondValue\"}]"
```

How can I encode the response array to be an actual JSON object?

Comment: What version of php are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you’re doing this:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);    
$response = json_encode($response);
```

Unclear what the returned data is from `https://endpointfortheapi.com`, but it seems to me that you are taking a source JSON response & then double-encoding the response when you do `json_encode` again.

If you send a plain string to `json_encode` instead of an object or array—it will just escape it exactly as you are seeing. So I would just remove or comment out that line & see if that clears things up.

Also, you should be setting proper JSON headers in your PHP before the echo. So based on what I mention above & the headers I would refactor your PHP code to be like this:

```
public function myaction() {

    $ch = curl_init();

    $endPoint = 'https://endpointfortheapi.com';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endPoint); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    // $response = json_encode($response);

    // header('X-JSON: (' . $response. ')');
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo $response;

    curl_close($ch);

}
```

I commented out the `X-JSON` header since [there is some controversy surrounding the use of that custom header](http://5.com/articles/ruby-developers-ignore-security-risks-claim-x-json-header-lsquonothing-serious-rsquo) which is used by some applications to automatically evaluate JSON data if they are using [the `Prototype` JavaScript framework](http://prototypejs.org). Not worth the hassle if you are not using Prototype and don’t care about such things.

Comment: I'm intrigued by that `X-JSON` header in there; what's the advantage of echoing the content twice like that, and isn't there a risk of it creating a broken HTTP response?

Comment: Also, the correct content type for JSON is `application/json`, no `x-` http://stackoverflow.com/q/477816/157957

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for your help. I believe the data that is being returned from the API I'm using is an array. I'm under the impression that `json_decode()` converts an array to a JSON object. I'm setting my headers using `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. I just didn't include it in my question.

Answer (score -1):

Set the `dataType` to `json` in your ajax request:

```
$(function() {

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/mycontroller/myaction/',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {       
        console.log(data);
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Setting the `dataType` will turn a json string into a json object. The OP will most likely need this even if there are other errors in his code.

Comment: @oOle2 @JakeGould Adding `dataType` to my Ajax request and removing `json_encode()` fixed my issue. Thanks guys!